# When does log4j2 load the configuration file?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I read the configuration manual page https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html
and it just says

> Log4j has the ability to automatically configure itself during initialization. When Log4j starts it will locate all the ConfigurationFactory plugins and arrange them in weighted order from highest to lowest.

It just says *When Log4j starts* but it doesn't mean anything precise.

So the question is: **when does log4j2 read the configuration file?**

Comment: `static` initialiser - when the logging gets classloaded.

Answer (score 0):

in case of web-applications (servlet 3.0 and above), log4j2 starts with your web-application. therefore you should include the log4j-web.jar this jar is a web-fragment, wich is configured to be loaded before any other web-fragments in the project. [at this point log4j2 searches for a configuration-file to load](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)

please refer to https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html and take a look at the screenshot [image: eclipse-screenshot]